# Make caret's genetric feature selection faster

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, r-caret

I am trying to optimize a xgboost tree by using feature selection with caret's genetic algorithm

```
results <- gafs(iris[,1:4], iris[,5],
               iters = 2,
               method = "xgbTree",
               metric = "Accuracy",
               gafsControl = gafsControl(functions=caretGA, method="cv", repeats=2, verbose = TRUE),
               trConrol = trainControl(method = "cv", classProbs = TRUE, verboseIter = TRUE)
               )
```

this is however very slow and this even though I am just using `iters = 2` instead of `iters = 200` as would be more appropriate. What can I do to make this faster?

Comment: Parallelisation, reduced `popSize`, `repeats = 1`, ...

Comment: @JuliusVainora: What `popSize` should I use and how do I parallise?

Comment: Not sure what are recommendations for `popSize`. The end of the "Details" section in `?gafs` is on parallelisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of parallelising the `gafs()` function using the `doParallel` package and modifying a few other parameters to make it faster.  Where possible I include run times.

The original code is using cross-validation (`method = "cv"`) not repeated cross-validation (`method = "repeatedcv"`), so I believe the `repeats = 2` parameter is ignored.  I didn't include that option in the parallelised example.

**First**, using the original code without any modifications or parallelisation:

```
> library(caret)
> data(iris)

> set.seed(1)
> st.01 <- system.time(results.01 <- gafs(iris[,1:4], iris[,5],
                                          iters  = 2, 
                                          method = "xgbTree", 
                                          metric = "Accuracy",
                                          gafsControl = gafsControl(functions = caretGA, 
                                                                    method  = "cv", 
                                                                    repeats = 2, 
                                                                    verbose = TRUE),
                                          trConrol = trainControl(method = "cv", 
                                                                  classProbs  = TRUE, 
                                                                  verboseIter = TRUE)))

Fold01 1 0.9596575 (1)
Fold01 2 0.9596575->0.9667641 (1->1, 100.0%) *
Fold02 1 0.9598146 (1)
Fold02 2 0.9598146->0.9641482 (1->1, 100.0%) *
Fold03 1 0.9502661 (1)
```

I ran the above code overnight (8 to 10 hours) but stopped it running because it took too long to finish.  A very rough estimate of run time would be at least 24 hours.

**Second**, including reduced `popSize` parameter (from 50 to 20), `allowParallel` and `genParallel` options to `gafsControl()` and finally reduced `number` of folds (from 10 to 5) in both `gafsControl()` and `trControl()`:

```
> library(doParallel)
> cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores() - 1)
> registerDoParallel(cl)

> set.seed(1)
> st.09 <- system.time(results.09 <- gafs(iris[,1:4], iris[,5],
                                          iters   = 2, 
                                          popSize = 20, 
                                          method  = "xgbTree", 
                                          metric  = "Accuracy",
                                          gafsControl = gafsControl(functions = caretGA, 
                                                                    method    = "cv", 
                                                                    number    = 5, 
                                                                    verbose   = TRUE, 
                                                                    allowParallel = TRUE, 
                                                                    genParallel   = TRUE),
                                          trConrol = trainControl(method      = "cv", 
                                                                  number      = 5, 
                                                                  classProbs  = TRUE, 
                                                                  verboseIter = TRUE)))

 final GA
 1 0.9508099 (4)
 2 0.9508099->0.9561501 (4->1, 25.0%) *
 final model
> st.09
   user   system  elapsed
   3.536    0.173 4152.988
```

My system has 4 cores but as specified it is using only 3, and I verified that it was running 3 R processes.

The `gafsControl()` documentation describes `allowParallel` and `genParallel` like so:

- `allowParallel`: if a parallel backend is loaded and available,
  should the function use it?
- `genParallel`: if a parallel backend is loaded and available, should
           'gafs' use it tp parallelize the fitness calculations within
           a generation within a resample?

The caret documentation suggests the `allowParallel` option will give a bigger run time improvement than the `genParallel` options:
https://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-using-genetic-algorithms.html

I would expect at least slightly different results from the parallelised code compared to the original code.  Here are the results from the parallelised code:

```
> results.09

Genetic Algorithm Feature Selection

150 samples
4 predictors
3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'

Maximum generations: 2
Population per generation: 20
Crossover probability: 0.8
Mutation probability: 0.1
Elitism: 0

Internal performance values: Accuracy, Kappa
Subset selection driven to maximize internal Accuracy

External performance values: Accuracy, Kappa
Best iteration chose by maximizing external Accuracy
External resampling method: Cross-Validated (5 fold)

During resampling:
  * the top 4 selected variables (out of a possible 4):
    Petal.Width (80%), Petal.Length (40%), Sepal.Length (20%), Sepal.Width (20%)
  * on average, 1.6 variables were selected (min = 1, max = 4)

In the final search using the entire training set:
   * 4 features selected at iteration 1 including:
     Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width
   * external performance at this iteration is

   Accuracy       Kappa
     0.9467      0.9200
```

Comment: a) This is such long training time! The iris dataset is *very* small. How could anyone hope that xgboost finishes in any reasonable time for a real-life industrial dataset... I am not expert in classification (I am mostly researching unsupervised methods), so I am really surprised - if not confused... What is going on here?

Comment: b) How long did it take the second version to run?

Comment: b) The total run time for the second version was 4,153 seconds (see elapsed time above) and was stored in the st.09 variable.  Details for the three numbers in st.09 can be found with ?proc.time in an R session.

Comment: a) I agree, training time is too long. There are two levels of cross-validation though.  I'd bet gafs() isn't slow on the xgboost aspect unless it's being called too many times. My guess is that it's slow on the genetic algorithm aspect. One alternative feature selection method within the caret package is the 'simulated annealing for feature selection' function, safs(), but again that has two levels of cross-validation. A slightly different option is using a regularisation method for feature selection, like glmnet, with the train() function which would have only one level of cross-validation.

Comment: Tree based ensemble methods like xgboost should be fairly robust to irrelevant variables.  Variables which cannot discriminate between outcomes will not be selected for tree splitting.  The xgb.plot.importance() function in the xgboost R library plots feature importance as a bar graph.  Excluding features which are consistently at the bottom of the variable importance chart is worth considering.  The caret train() function with method='xgboost' will be a great deal faster than the gafs() function on the iris data.

Comment: I've tried profiling the gafs() function using the lineprof package to see where it was spending most time.  As expected it runs much slower.  I stopped the profile after 3 days.  Is there anything else I can add to this answer to get it accepted?

Comment: I guess the answer is "there is only so much that can be done" ;-). I am gonna except.